# Find or Replace for text area (selection)

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't use the Find or Replace feature with text selection in my Android Studio.

[image: Find something in code selection]
[image: The setting in my finding]

The result always shows *No occurrences of 'xxx' found in Selection*.

My Android Studio version is 1.2.2. Even today I updated the Android Studio into the newest 1.3.0, it still doesn't work. But my friend's one works.

My computer OS is Windows 8.1. My friend's one is Windows 7.

I had tried to re-install Android Studio without removing the user settings. Still doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: is it because you are using 'custom' instead of module/directory? Even if you use `Current file` as custom selection, it will work

Comment: `Current File` works well. But no matter what characters I put into the search box (through ctrl + shift + F), nothing is always found.

Comment: I also tried it, if you add first few words of selected text, it will match. Example - you selected 'crocodile is cool', and search for 'croco', it will fetch the result. Though that's not how it should be.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's working in windows, but in mac cmd + R, try ctrl + R[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to find the phrase _camera in the current selection? If so just use find and replace (ctrl + F) on the whole java file rather than Find in files and limiting the scope to the selection.

Comment: I was refactorying my code and need to replace some variables. The *Replace characters in selection* ( through ctrl + shift + R ) is most convenient I think.