# Search only inside an XML element / path instead of complete file?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-styles

Imagine I have a large xml file and I only want to search inside a given element, how can I do this in Android Studio?

Example file:

```
<style name="a">
    // much stuff here
</style>

<style name="b">
    // many items
    <item name="iWantToSearchForThis" />
    // many more items
</style>

<style name="c">
    // much stuff here
</style>
```

I do not want to search in the complete file, but only inside `<style name="b">...</style>`. How can I do that? Ideally something like putting the cursor inside `<style name="b">` and then starting some search function would be great.

Comment: Here is an option https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555184/7210237
It is not exactly "search in specific element", rather search in selection.
And works only with Cmd+R / Ctrl+R (aka Replace...), not with Cmd+F / Ctrl+F. But still an option.